# How to format time to '2:34 hrs', '0:34 hrs' etc in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, time

I am writing a query that is selecting two times and calculating the difference between these, where one is the start and the other is the finish to find out the duration. However both are set to TIME types in mysql. How can i format the time instead of showing HH:MM:SS to '[OPTIONAL H]H':MM hrs'

Do i use the extract function? 
I presume i have to wrap the TIMEDIFF around something else?

my sql code is as follows:

```
SELECT operator_no, log_in_time, TIMEDIFF(log_in_time,log_out_time) AS Duration
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, wrap it in `TIME_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT operator_no, log_in_time,
       TIME_FORMAT(
           TIMEDIFF(log_in_time, log_out_time),
           '%H:%i hrs'
       ) AS Duration
```

Comment: would this not work too?

SELECT operator_no, log_in_time,
       CONCAT(EXTRACT(HOUR_MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFF 
             (log_in_time,end_time)) + 'hrs'
       ) AS Duration

Answer (score 0):

would this not work too?

SELECT operator_no, log_in_time,
     CONCAT(EXTRACT(HOUR_MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFF (log_in_time,end_time)) + 'hrs' ) 
     AS Duration

Comment: `EXTRACT` would produce a format as `HHMM` without a colon.  Also, I'm not sure how it deals with hours that are greater than 23 as it's primarily a DATE function.